# How to update SCSS on Wordpress?

Tags: ruby, wordpress, ftp, sass, zurb-foundation

I recently learn how to use SASS, on local. And I found out that it is possible to use it in a wordpress theme.
I manage to install and use it without problem. But now I want to customize _settings.scss, I don't know how to transform my scss in css (I used Grunt, in a console using ruby to do so in local.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be editing your files locally and uploading once finished rather than modifying files on the server. There should never be any need to compile SASS on the server itself.

If you really have to edit on the server you could login using SSH and start the watcher (install sass and run sass --watch with your settings).